# using Sublime Text 3 cli from within another service to open an new window creates a temp file

Tags: macos, applescript, sublimetext3, automator, karabiner

I've been setting up a Karabiner (Launcher Mode) shortcut to open a new Sublime Text window.

Normally I call `subl -n` from a terminal window to bring up a new sublime window. Karabiner lets you specify shell scripts as shortcuts to run, so I tried `/usr/local/bin/subl -n`

It works, but, whereas calling `subl -n` from a terminal window (or `/usr/local/bin/subl -n`) opens a new window with a "blank" file, calling it through Karabiner opens a temp file at `tmp/subl stdin YEd3Bc.txt` (YEd3Bc is six random numbers/digits) in a new window

It also blocks Karabiner from launching anything else until you close the window, as if I had called `subl -n -w "tmp/subl stdin YEd3Bc.txt"`

I thought it was a problem with Karabiner, and tried to work around it by using Automator and Applescript to create wrappers for a shell script, but both of them had the same problem, opening temp files at `/tmp/subl stdin random.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used that particular software (Karabiner) however it could be opening a temp file due to the user that is launching the command (Karabiner) not having access to the default path to store the temp file there to which it creates a unique named file in the `/tmp` directory. You could try adding the following `su -u "your user without quotes" -c /use/local/bin/subl -n`. As for the locking of (Karabiner) that is most likely due to the internals of Karabiner and how it opens a sub process to the subl binary along with sublimes nature of staying at the foreground. You can attempt a `&` at the end of the command to send it to the background allowing Karabiner the ability to continue processing.